# get elements by array name JS, JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this HTML

```
<input type="text" name="object[A][Name]">
<input type="text" name="object[A][Description]">
<input type="text" name="object[B][Name]">
<input type="text" name="object[B][Description]">
```

but when i try to get with:

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("object");
var x = document.getElementsByName("object[]");
var x = document.getElementsByName("object[][]");
var x = $("[name='object']");
var x = $("[name='object[]']");
var x = $("[name='object[][]']");
```

x is empty

I need get A, Name/Description and value

Normally I process this names in PHP like this:

```
foreach($_POST['object'] as $objectgroup=>$value)
{
  /* work here */
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect a different result? Please explain.

Comment: Here's the link to the API with all the available selectors https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.

Answer (score 0):

Use `^=` to match the starting string:

```
var x = $("[name^='object']"); // Get all elements
var x = $("[name^='object[A']"); // Get only "object[A]" elements
var x = $("[name='object[A][Description]']"); // Matches full element name
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/azbzagec/)

Answer (score 0):

You want to select inputs whose `name` attribute *starts with* "object", so use the `^=` operator ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)):

```
var x = $('input[name^=object]');
```